# Making achartengine not clickable

Tags: android, achartengine

I want the parent View of my ChartView to be clickable.  However, I'm not able to do this because the ChartView object eats the click.  I've tried several things to make the click "go through" the ChartView and register on the View containing it.

```
                chartdata.mChartView = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(this, chartdata.mDataset, chartdata.mRenderer);
                chartdata.mChartView.setClickable(false);
                chartdata.mChartView.setTouchDelegate(null);
                chartdata.mChartView.setOnClickListener(null);
                chartdata.mChartView.setOnTouchListener(null);
```

I have so far been unsuccessful.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

try :

```
chartdata.mRenderer.setPanEnabled(false, false);
chartdata.mRenderer.setZoomEnabled(false, false);
```

Comment: I've given this a shot with no success